# Android - get Days, Months, and Years since a previous date

Tags: android, date, kotlin

How in Android can I get and display the number of days, months, and years since a date?

For example, let's say the previous date is:

```
02/02/2017
```

and today's date is:

```
04/30/2018
```

I would want it to say something like:

```
1 year, 2 months, 28 days
```

I think I need to get total days like so:

```
long msDiff = Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis() - oldCalendarDate.getTimeInMillis();
long daysDiff = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toDays(msDiff);
```

but how do I convert the amount of days to be legible as years, months, and days? Keeping in mind that not all months have 31 days.

Because this way, I am only getting

```
452 days
```

As the result. But I want it to be more like 1 year, 2 months, 28 days.

Is there a better solution?

Also I want to get the old date like so in a variable:

```
val oldCalendarDate = GregorianCalendar(2017, 3, 30).time
```

but it's not working at all with the above code. Yes I'm aware that variable is in kotlin because I'm working in kotlin so pardon the syntax. I think the more issue about this is how the integers are formatted. I already converted the other java code to kotlin but I posted it as java for this post since more people are familiar with java.

Comment: try https://stackoverflow.com/q/19667473/6880632

Comment: Already have an answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19667994/5167909

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to show milliseconds in days:hours:min:seconds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19667473/how-to-show-milliseconds-in-dayshoursminseconds)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Calendar` Object can resolve this problem

```
val msDiff = Calendar.getInstance().timeInMillis - oldCalendarDate.timeInMillis;
val calDiff = Calendar.getInstance()
calDiff.timeInMillis = msDiff
val msg = "${calDiff.get(Calendar.YEAR) - 1970} year, ${calDiff.get(Calendar.MONTH)} months, $calDiff.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)} days"
```

Comment: this works great.

How can I use the same code to also calculator the amount of days until the same date (like a birth date) that next happens?

for example, let's say "birthdate" variable is  3/30/2015.   Today's date is   3/25/2018.  I want to send a message that says "birthdate is in 5 days!"

Answer (score -1):

You try this code,

```
 long different = your today date - your previous date;
     // take both dates in date format.

        long secondsInMilli = 1000;
        long minutesInMilli = secondsInMilli * 60;
        long hoursInMilli = minutesInMilli * 60;
        long daysInMilli = hoursInMilli * 24;
        long mothsInMilli = daysInMilli * 30;
        long yearInMilli = mothsInMilli * 12;

        long elapsedYear = different / yearInMilli;
        different = different % yearInMilli;
        long diffYear = elapsedYear;
        Log.d("", "difference of years : " + diffYear);

        long elapsedMonths = different / mothsInMilli;
        different = different % mothsInMilli;
        long diffMonth = elapsedMonths;
        Log.d("", "difference of Months : " + diffMonth);

        long elapsedDays = different / daysInMilli;
        different = different % daysInMilli;
        long diffDays = elapsedDays;
        Log.d("", "difference of Days : " + diffDays);
```

Using this code I got proper difference, It may helps you also. Show below, **I had two dates**:

**pastdate::**`Mon Mar 26 13:06:52 GMT+05:30 2018`

**todayDate::**`Mon Apr 30 13:06:52 GMT+05:30 2018`

**I got difference of month,year and days like below:-**

```
    difference of Years : 0
    difference of Months : 1
    difference of Days : 4
```